# German Umlauts (but only uppercase) are broken

Tags: openvz, proxmox, dpkg, utf-8, charset

I have a proxmox3 server. I login via SSH. Umlauts (öäüÜÖÄ) works well - nevertheless if upper or lowercase.

Then I login in my openvz node (debian wheezy) via:

vzctl enter 100

In this node,

- on CLI umlauts are not work
- in a textfile only lowercase Umlauts work (üöäÜÖÄ gives: üöä�^��^��^)

Any time i login "locales" gives me following (even if I did dpkg-reconfigure locales, AND edit /etc/enviroment and set it to:

```
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Locales inside openvz-node gives:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I have no clue, what's wrong here. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Ok, found out this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, today I did this:

First, I enter this on commandline:

```
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then I restart the node. Now it works. Really Strange. Thougt I did the same thing the last 2 Days.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.